# How to Fix Floating Point Discrepencies in Python Pandas Dataframes?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I'm reading a CSV file into a Panda's dataframe.  When retrieving the data, I'm getting slightly different values then the original data.

I believe it has something to do with the way Python represents decimals.  But how do I fix it/work around it?

CSV data example:

```
1313331280,10.4,0.779
1313334917,10.4,0.316
1313334917,10.4,0.101
1313340309,10.5,0.15
1313340309,10.5,1.8
```

Pandas dataframe:

```
df = pd.read_csv(csv_file_full_path, names=['time','price', 'volume'])
```

The output:

```
ORDERS_DATA_FRAME.iloc[0]['volume']

source file value = 0.779
the pandas output value = 0.77900000000000003
```

The data is getting changed when read into the Pandas dataframe.  What's the fix?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is floating point math broken?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Comment: Something else is going on here.  First, I'm not doing any math.  I'm just reading data that was read into the Panda's dataframe.   Next, it's Python, not Javascript

Comment: No, it's exactly the same. `0.779` **cannot** be represented exactly as a floating point number, so you see *almost* that number in the dataframe. Language is irrelevant. See e.g. http://floating-point-gui.de/. Also, note that the dataframe doesn't belong to a panda ;o)

Comment: Regardless, then, is there a fix so that when I read that back that variable I get 0.779 exactly?  As in the same number that was put into the dataframe?

Comment: Not unless you can come up with a way to represent all of the infinite real numbers in a finite number of bits... Again, you cannot represent that number exactly in floating point arithmetic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Though the issue is because of the floating point arithmetic, if you know the maximum number of decimals your column has, you can use `round(float_number, number_of_decimals)` to get back your normal values. Alternatively, you can read the column as string and then convert it to float by using `float(float_number_string)`.

Comment: On the second suggestion of reading as as string and converting to a float (non literal float), its still stored as a binary representation; even-though its displayed as `0.779` when you print the variable; its actually not the same value